# Current line number from a System.Xml.XmlReader (C# & .Net)

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xmlreader, line-numbers

Does anyone know how I can get the current line number of an System.Xml.XmlReader?  I am trying to record where in a file I find Xml elements.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Take advantage of the [`IXmlLineInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.ixmllineinfo.aspx) interface supported by an `XmlReader`:

```
IXmlLineInfo xmlInfo = (IXmlLineInfo)reader;
int lineNumber = xmlInfo.LineNumber;
```

Comment: Looks like bad practice. As XmlReader does not inherit IXmlLineInfo then implementations of this abstract class may not implement the interface. A check for support of the interface is needed.

Comment: Please Use IXmlLineInfo xmlInfo =  reader as IXmlLineInfo; This good code practice. @shuvra

Comment: I can confirm @SerG 's comment because `XmlNodeReader` does not inherit `IXmlLineInfo`

Comment: Got myself a nice null out of that. So it depends which XmlReader implementation you got. Not safe.

Comment: What if LineNumber or LinePosition exceeds the maximum for a signed 32-bit integer? Yes, that is a problem I have at this time.

Answer (score 3):

Expanding on the `IXmlLineInfo` interface, the documentation for this is pretty bad; from doing a bit of digging, I can tell you the following:

1) `System.Xml.XmlReader` is abstract, so you're never going to be dealing with an instance of this, as such, the fact that it doesn't implement `IXmlLineInfo` isn't massively concerning (although, if it did, it would make everything just that little bit easier :) )

2) The `System.Xml.IXmlLineInfo` interface provides two properties: `LineNumber` and `LinePosition` (which are the things we care about), plus a method: `HasLineInfo()` which, according to the documentation, will let you know if an implementor can return the lineinfo.

3) Of the documented inheritors of `System.Xml.XmlReader`, we have:

```
System.Xml.XmlDictionaryReader - abstract, used by WCF for serialization, no IXmlLineInfo
System.Xml.XmlNodeReader - used when reading a node, no IXmlLineInfo
System.Xml.XmlTextReader - used when reading a stream of data, has IXmlLineInfo
System.Xml.XmlValidatingReader - used when reading a stream of data and validating, has IXmlLineInfo.
```

Looking at the above list, the `XmlDictionaryReader` is going to be used internally, the `XmlNodeReader` is going to be used when you've passed in a node to be read (which, having been parsed, is already untethered from its source document), the `XmlTextReader` and `XmlValidtingReader` (both of which implement `IXmlLineInfo`), are going to be used when you're reading from a document.  So, the long and the short of it seems to be that if it's possible or useful to give you position information, the framework will do so.

That being said, the documentation seems to be very light.  Having just done this, I ended up doing (with _xr being an unknown concrete implementation of `System.Xml.XmlReader`):

```
string position = "(unknown)";
    if (_xr != null && typeof(System.Xml.IXmlLineInfo).IsInstanceOfType(_xr) &&
((System.Xml.IXmlLineInfo)_xr).HasLineInfo())
    {
        System.Xml.IXmlLineInfo li = (System.Xml.IXmlLineInfo)_xr;
        position = "(" + li.LineNumber.ToString() + "," + li.LinePosition.ToString() + ")";
    }
```

With all of that being said, when I actually run the code above, the type of _xr ends up being `System.Xml.XsdValidatingReader` (good luck finding documentation on that!), which inherits from `System.Xml.XmlReader`, but doesn't inherit from `System.Xml.XmlValidatingReader` or `System.Xml.XmlTextReader`.  As such, it's probably wise to use an approach like the above.